# phrase to describe the diversity of age range of a group of people

Tags: word-choice

Would it be correct to use "chronologically diverse" to describe a group of people whose ages range from very young to very old? If not, what would be a better phrase to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common phrase to use here is simply:

> ***a group of all ages***

Comment: Or "of varying ages".

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail- Yes. Good.